# CRM : Linked Entities collection is empty

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have the following query to get account with related entity = primary contact. Executing this query I successfully get accounts, but related entity collection is empty.

```
    var _service = _getService();
    var q = new QueryExpression("account");
    q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name");

    q.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("account", "contact", 
"primarycontactid", "contactid", JoinOperator.Inner));
    q.LinkEntities[0].Columns.AllColumns = true;
    q.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "temp";

    EntityCollection ec = _service.RetrieveMultiple(q);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**: to check related entities fields I use

```
for (int i = 0; i < ec.Entities.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write(ec.Entities[i].RelatedEntities.Count + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear when you join entities in that way all the related entity information (contact in your case) will be returned along with fields of primary entity (account in your case).

To get field from related entity you will have to check the same entity like `(string)ec.Entities[0].GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("temp.fullname").Value`

Comment: Updated my question. Do you mean that I should look for related fields in my `ec.Entities[n].Attributes`?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can found it. Maybe, you know, what to do if I need to have dynamic amount of linked entities? If I don't know for example how much child contacts can account have?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this "dynamic amount of linked entities" thing?

Comment: I have account with 5 child contacts. I want to add their fields as linked entity to parent account. But another account have only 2 contacts, so the amount of child entities shouldn't be hardcoded.

Comment: If go away from realisation, I want to have an parent object with child objects to call them like (pseudocode): `account.contacts[i]`. And I want `account` be an entity type, so I can't extend it.

Comment: This can't be done in 1 call. You will have to do it in 2 steps - 1 is to get all accounts you want (without children records) and 2-nd is to go through your accounts and fetch child contacts.